# What Happened to Rhaegal?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Towards the end of Season 7 Episode 6 we see:

> The Nights King take down Viserion with an ice spear.

At this point Rhaegal is flying next to him but then seems to fly off over the mountains and away from the danger.

A short while later we are back at the wall and Dany is looking out over the lands presumably looking for Jon. However, over head we only see Drogon flying about.

Assuming I saw everything correctly **do we know what happened to Rhaegal?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Update: We do know what happened to Rhaegal!

After the finale aired, Rhaegal was likely mourning in the loss of his brother with his other brother Drogon. The two are seen flying into the Dragon pit, where the Dragons of old shrunk in size and became small, along side Daenerys for the meeting amongst the three Kings and Queen of <s>Middle-earth</s> Westeros.

---

S7E6 Assumptions:

### <s>No, we don't know what happened</s>

Through the rest of the episode we don't get to see Rhaegal again. We have every reason to believe he's alive and back with Dany. It would be very unlikely for the creators to have the White Walkers either turn him without showing us. Or have him flee in panic without using it as a cliff hanger.

The fact that Rhaegal is with Daenerys will likely be confirmed next episode. Even though I'm the trailer for the next episode (S7E7 spoilers)

> Neither dragon was shown in the fleet sailing to Kings' Landing or at the meeting between the two queens.

His lack of presence can be seen in this video, after Benjen's rescue:

Part 3 of the episode with the earlier fight can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/GWeRWUNaMUw)

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is: "We don't know". +1 for the supporting evidence and OOU explanation of why he's likely okay when the show revealed nothing.